Getting `ReferenceError` while pre-rendering in StencilJS
I'm developing a webapp with StencilJS (using the native router and store). The build works fine with stencil build but throws an error when I try to pre-render using stencil build --prerender
Here is the output:

> app-frontend@0.0.1 build
> stencil build --prerender

[21:57.4]  @stencil/core
[21:57.7]  v2.13.0 
[22:02.0]  build, app, prod mode, started ...
[22:02.0]  transpile started ...
[22:11.0]  transpile finished in 8.93 s
[22:11.0]  copy started ...
[22:11.0]  generate hydrate app started ...
[22:11.0]  generate lazy started ...
[22:11.9]  copy finished (3 files) in 892 ms
[22:24.4]  generate hydrate app finished in 13.43 s
[22:30.9]  generate lazy finished in 19.98 s
[22:31.0]  build finished in 28.97 s

[22:33.9]  prerendering started ...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx browserslist@latest --update-db
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
[22:34.5]  prerendering failed in 616 ms

[ ERROR ]  Hydrate Error
           ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getRenderingRef' before initialization at stencilSubscription
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:4759:5)
           at createStore
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:4908:13)
           at hydrateAppClosure
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:4912:19)
           at hydrateFactory
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:19734:3)
           at render
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:20001:9)
           at
           /Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:19933:62
           at new Promise (<anonymous>) at Object.hydrateDocument
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/dist/hydrate/index.js:19925:33)
           at prerenderWorker
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/node_modules/@stencil/core/compiler/stencil.js:9733:46)
           at prerenderWorker
           (/Users/tuhinb/_/projckt/starter/development/webapp-starter/webapp/dev/frontend/node_modules/@stencil/core/compiler/stencil.js:11640:42)


Someone faced this situation before but the answer was not posted.
Thanks for reading, waiting for your responses.

This has nothing to do with ionic but you tagged it as such. -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
